# Django w/ Apache: Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to

Tags: django, apache, ip-address

got my server working with Apache, ran it and everything was peachy. Added an html file to the templates and set a the views.py and urls.py to render it at the correct url. Synced everything via git, but when I issue `sudo python manage.py runserver 123.456.789.000:80` (with my IP filled in, to run on port 80), I get `Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to.`

Puzzling, because I just ran the server successfully at that IP address...

Thoguhts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got Apache running on port 80, as it is by default, then of course you can't run `runserver` at that address as well. Although I don't know why you'd want to.